# Access to Activeadmin Resources collection in an app initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, activeadmin

I have this code in a Rails initializer file to disable a specific filter for all my admin resources:

```
ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.values.each do |resource|
  resource.remove_filter :some_common_filter if resource.is_a? ActiveAdmin::Resource
end
```

but at this moment of the program execution the collection of resources is still empty (resources.count == 0) so no call to #remove_filter is done.

Same happend inside the **ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|** block and using *config* instead of *ActiveAdmin.application*.

Later on a console I can access all my admin resources, but not in the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution using the `after_load` hook

```
ActiveAdmin.after_load do |app|
  app.namespaces.each do |name, _namespace|
    name.resources.values.each do |resource|
      resource.remove_filter :my_common_filter if resource.is_a?(ActiveAdmin::Resource) && resource.filters.include?(:my_common_filter)
    end
  end
```

end